# Exponent of primes in factorial n

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number and $V2,V3$ and $V5$ denote the exponent of $2,3$ and $5$ in $n!$ respectively. Then it true that $(2^{V2})^2(3^{V3})^2(5^{V5})^2>n!$. I have verified it by calculator. How do I prove it mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, for example $59!=2^{54}\cdot 3^{27} \cdot 5^{13}\cdot d$ where $d$ is coprime to $2,3$ and $5$ (see [factorize 59!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+59%21)), yet
$$
(2^{54}\cdot 3^{27} \cdot 5^{13})^2 \not > 59!,
$$
see [is (2^54 * 3^27 * 5^13)^2 > 59!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+%282%5E54+*+3%5E27+*+5%5E13%29%5E2+%3E+59%21).

Comment: OK, it's false.

Comment: Is this true for $V2, V3, V5, V7$ ? If not then how many $V$'s do we need? I suspect it won't work for any number of $V$'s.

Comment: Yes it fails for that case too, $111!$ seems to be counterexample. Of course $n=1$ is counterexample for all cases.